# Vue watch value from parent is in reverse

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I have a custom component that lets users type in text and sends it to the backend where I do some computation and spit the new text back out with html in it.

My problem is when the user types into this textarea, it reverses all the text and keeps the cursors at the beginning of the textarea. So now 'foo bar' becomes 'rab oof'... This only has happened since I added in `watch`. I could delete the watcher, but I need it (or need another way) to apply my updates to the textarea, via the `foo` variable when I set `foo` equal to something from the parent.

`console.log(v)` writes out the reverse text.
 Any idea how to change this?

Custom componet:

```
    <template>
  <div contenteditable="true" @input="updateHTML" class="textareaRoot"></div>
</template>
<script>
export default {
  name: 'htmlTextArea',
  props:['value'],
  mounted: function () {
    this.$el.innerHTML = this.value;
  },
  watch: {
    value(v) {
      this.$el.innerHTML =  v; //v is the reverse text. 
    }
  },
  methods: {
    updateHTML: function(e) {
      this.$emit('input', e.target.innerHTML);

    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Parent that uses custom component:

```
    <htmlTextArea id="textarea" v-model="foo"></htmlTextArea>

...
<script>
...
methods: {
        triggerOnClick() {
            this.foo = 'something';//Without the watcher, when I change this.foo to something the actual textarea does not display the new data that I assigned to foo. But in Vue dev tools I can see the new change. 
        }
```

UPDATE:

```js
Vue.component('html-textarea',{
  template:'<div contenteditable="true" @input="updateHTML"></div>',
  props:['value'],
  mounted: function () {
    this.$el.innerHTML = this.value;
  },
  watch: {
    value(v) {
      this.$el.innerHTML =  v;
    }
  },
  methods: {
    updateHTML: function(e) {
      this.$emit('input', e.target.innerHTML);

    }
  }
});

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data () {
        return {
            foo: '',
        }
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue"></script>

<div id="app">Type here:
 <html-textarea spellcheck="false" id="textarea" v-model="foo">        </html-textarea>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on *when I set the model equal to something that the backend returns*?

Comment: @acdcjunior Sure, in the parent I can set the model `this.foo = 'something';`. The text -area **only** changes my input into reverse, not when I set `foo` equal to something.

Comment: Create a working snippet that demonstrates your problem.

Comment: @connexo code snippet in update^

Comment: You should use v-model, I see no reason to modify the DOM like this.

Comment: @EricGuan I would, however I need the model to bind to a text input area that allows for html to be displayed as html and not text. This was the only way I could find that does this. I'm open to other ways though as this is a little hectic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that when you set the `innerHTML` of a `contenteditable` element, you lose the selection (cursor position).

So you should perform the following steps when setting:

- save the current cursor position;
- set the `innerHTML`;
- restore the cursor position.

Saving and restoring is the tricky part. Luckily I got these two handy functions that do the job for latest IE and newer. See below.

```js
function saveSelection(containerEl) {
  var range = window.getSelection().getRangeAt(0);
  var preSelectionRange = range.cloneRange();
  preSelectionRange.selectNodeContents(containerEl);
  preSelectionRange.setEnd(range.startContainer, range.startOffset);
  var start = preSelectionRange.toString().length;

  return {
    start: start,
    end: start + range.toString().length
  }
}

function restoreSelection(containerEl, savedSel) {
  var charIndex = 0, range = document.createRange();
  range.setStart(containerEl, 0);
  range.collapse(true);
  var nodeStack = [containerEl],
    node, foundStart = false,
    stop = false;

  while (!stop && (node = nodeStack.pop())) {
    if (node.nodeType == 3) {
      var nextCharIndex = charIndex + node.length;
      if (!foundStart && savedSel.start >= charIndex && savedSel.start <= nextCharIndex) {
        range.setStart(node, savedSel.start - charIndex);
        foundStart = true;
      }
      if (foundStart && savedSel.end >= charIndex && savedSel.end <= nextCharIndex) {
        range.setEnd(node, savedSel.end - charIndex);
        stop = true;
      }
      charIndex = nextCharIndex;
    } else {
      var i = node.childNodes.length;
      while (i--) {
        nodeStack.push(node.childNodes[i]);
      }
    }
  }

  var sel = window.getSelection();
  sel.removeAllRanges();
  sel.addRange(range);
}


Vue.component('htmltextarea', {
  template: '#hta',
  name: 'htmlTextArea',
  props:['value'],
  mounted: function () {
    this.$el.innerHTML = this.value;
  },
  watch: {
    value(v) {
      if (v === 'yes') {
        let selection = saveSelection(this.$el);
        this.$el.innerHTML = 'no!';
       this.$emit('input', 'no!');
        restoreSelection(this.$el, selection);
      }
    }
  },
  methods: {
    updateHTML: function(e) {
      this.$emit('input', e.target.innerHTML);
    }
  }
});

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    foo: 'Clear this and type "yes" (without the quotes). It should become "no!".'
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue"></script>

<div id="app">
  <htmltextarea id="textarea" v-model="foo"></htmltextarea>
  <hr>
  Result: <pre>{{ foo }}</pre>
</div>
<template id="hta">
    <div contenteditable="true" @input="updateHTML" class="textareaRoot"></div>
</template>
```

In your app, I recommend you place them in a dedicated `.js` file, just for better organization.

Comment: have you tried to insert vue-component into contenteditable and get back insertion for feature editing?